# Windows - Communication channel between driver and application.?

Tags: driver, communication, message

I'm developing an application.My driver has some data to send to application and receive response.But i don't know what's the way to do it.
Can anyone recommend to me?
Thanks so much.
regards,

Answer (score 3):

You can easily send asynchronous read requests to the device and hold them in the driver in a IRP queue.

This is called inverted call.

See this [article](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=94) on the technique.

When you send a request to the driver, you can specify, that the used mode pointer is kept alive. With this, you can directly communicate through this 'shared-memory'.

Comment: My driver is a firewall.It detects all incoming requests,and send request information<source/dest ip,port...> to my application.App will be response immediately.My driver receives message and check request will be block or allow.It's synchronous.Is above solution appropriate?

Comment: Updated the answer a bit. You can look into the WDK which contains a light weight filter driver for NDIS6. Maybe that could ease your work.

Comment: it means we can only use IOCTL for communication between driver and application?thank so much.

Comment: No you can use ReadFile/WriteFile requests. These are translated to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549327(v=vs.85).aspx.